# how to show values from mysql database without repeating values in php

Tags: php, mysql

When Iam showing database value from table its just repeating them according to content. First table which is content.

```
 id | category_id  |  name
-----------------------------
 1  |     2        |  Jason
 2  |     1        |  Richard
 3  |     2        |  John
```

category table:-

```
 id | name
 ---------
  1 | Manager
  2 | Employee
```

I use query:

```
$query=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM content");
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($query)){
                 $data[] = array('id'=> $row['id'],
                                'category_id' => $row['category_id'], 
                                'name' => $row['name']
                           );
            }
  for($i=0;$i<count($data);$i++){
     echo $data[$i]['category_id'];
     echo $data[$i]['name']."<br/>";
  }

  OUTPUT:-
  2 Jason 
  2 John
  1 Richard
```

But what i want is:-

```
 OUTPUT:-
 2 Jason John
 1 Richard
```

Now when echo out the result it shows me category_id 2 times having category_id=2 with its 2 name but what i want is to show only category_id 1 times and its corresponding 2 name of category_id=2. Please help.

Comment: `mysql_query` is an obsolete interface and should not be used in new applications as it's being removed in future versions of PHP. A modern replacement like [PDO is not hard to learn](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/). If you're new to PHP, a guide like [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) can help explain best practices.

Comment: @tadman yeah i get that but i want to do with using mysql_query.

Comment: your query should be fine, can you show us your result?

Comment: *"Now when echo out the result it shows me category_id 2 times having category_id=2 with its 2 name but what i want is to show only category_id 1 times and its corresponding 2 name of category_id=2."* - I'm having trouble understanding this. If you don't want repeats, use DISTINCT.

Comment: Use `DISTINCT` in your `SELECT` - Edit: Wait, there's something else, but I'll have to think about it.

Comment: You really do not want to be using `mysql_query` under any circumstances. You can use MySQL with `mysqli` or PDO. If this is legacy code and you're stuck with it, that's unfortunate, but new code shouldn't be using it. You'll get lots of warnings in PHP 5.5 and later, and rightfully so.

Comment: Please provide a sample output, because it's hard to understand what you really want to achieve.

Comment: @wolfgangwalther i showed in my question the output which i want to show.

Comment: You could use a [`GROUP_CONCAT()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) -> `SELECT \`category_id\`, GROUP_CONCAT(\`name\`) FROM content GROUP BY \`category_id\``

Comment: @Jason I've posted an answer below which worked well for me http://stackoverflow.com/a/26666861/1415724 however, it's based on an `category_id` of 2. I may have to alter my answer. Keep me posted.

Comment: @Jason I've made an edit actually. Reload it if you saw it.

Answer (score 2):

Try this approach, it worked for me:

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*), category_id, name, 

 GROUP_CONCAT(name separator ' ') as name FROM content  
 WHERE category_id=1 OR category_id=2 GROUP BY category_id 
 ORDER BY category_id DESC");

    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($query)){

        echo $row['category_id'] . " " . $row['name'] . "<br>";

    }
```

---

Plus, just a quick note about `mysql_*` functions being deprecated.

Use [**`mysqli` with prepared statements**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php), or [**PDO with prepared statements**](http://php.net/pdo.prepared-statements), *they're much safer.*

Answer (score 1):

Use this query:

```
SELECT id, category_id, GROUP_CONCAT(name SEPARATOR ' ') AS name
FROM content
GROUP BY category_id
```

See here for some quick tutorials on how to use GROUP BY and GROUP_CONCAT:
[w3schools.com / GROUP BY](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp)
[mysqltutorial.org / GROUP_CONCAT](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-group_concat/)

Comment: Hi @Jason if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't be using `mysql` as it is deprecated so to help you along I've done this with `PDO` to show its not as daunting as you may think.

PDO connection to database:

```
try{
    $db = new PDO ('mysql:host=YourHost;dbname=YourDatabaseName', 'YourDatabaseUserName', 'YourDatabasePassword');
    $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
}catch(PDOException $e){
    echo $e->getMessage();
    die();
}
```

The above connection uses a a `try` `catch` with a way of making any errors cleaner and easier to read by making use of the `getMessage()` function which removes a lot of the un needed info.

The query you're after in PDO:

```
$sql = "SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(name SEPARATOR ' ') AS names FROM yourtable GROUP BY category_id";
$query = $db->query($sql);
$results = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

foreach($results as $result){
    echo "<pre>", ($result->names), "</pre>";
}
```

This is the most basic way to use `PDO` to query your database but if you start using it like this you will find it easier to then develop the more in depth and secure ways of putting data in and getting data out of your database that help to prevent sql injection.

Hope this is a little food for thought and helps in getting you to move to a more secure API.

Answer (score 0):

try this

`select DISTINCT(*) from content`
or you can be more specific with ie DISTINCT(columnname)

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

// Using MySQL GROUP_CONCAT

$sql = 'SELECT category_id, GROUP_CONCAT(name separator \' \') FROM content GROUP BY category_id';


// Or PHP reduce as below
// Dummy Records
$records = [
    ['id' => 1, 'category_id' => 2, 'name' => 'Jason'],
    ['id' => 2, 'category_id' => 1, 'name' => 'Richard'],
    ['id' => 3, 'category_id' => 2, 'name' => 'John']
];

$result = array_reduce($records, function($carry, $record) {
    if (!array_key_exists($record['category_id'], $carry)) {
        $carry[$record['category_id']] = [];
    }

    $carry[$record['category_id']][] = $record['name'];

    return $carry;
}, []);

foreach ($result as $categoryId => $names) {
    echo $categoryId . ' ' . implode(' ', $names) . "\n";
}
```